# Ctrl + N does not work as a hotkey for New Folder ... in PyCharm in Ubuntu, KDE

Tags: pycharm, webstorm

[image]

I'm a little confused here why <kbd>Alt + Insert</kbd> is working hotkey for bringing up the drop down menu in the Project tool window for selecting a type of file or directory to create, but <kbd>Ctrl + N</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + N</kbd> don't work.

I don't have <kbd>Ctrl + N</kbd> bound to anything else in PyCharm, and nothing else (OS or programs) should be consuming the hotkey globally. I can <kbd>Ctrl + N</kbd> in Firefox.

I have the same issue in WebStorm.

I'm using:

- PyCharm Community 2021.1.1
- WebStorm 2021.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm a little confused here why `Alt + Insert` is working hotkey **for bringing up the drop down menu in the Project tool window for selecting a type of file or directory to create**, but `Ctrl + N` or `Ctrl + Alt + N` don't work.

You have <kbd>Ctrl + N</kbd> shortcut assigned to the wrong action. The one on your screenshot is for:

1. "Make New Folder" action
2. It will work in the File Chooser dialog only.

[image]

If you are after that "Make new file/folder" popup then you need to assign such shortcut to the `File | New...` action instead:

[image]